# Show that there is a common eigenvector to every operator of a family of triangularizable commutative operators.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

*Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension over a field $K$. Let $F$ be a family of triangularizable commutative operators.*

**Show that there is a common eigenvector to every operator of $F$, i.e, there is a non-null $v\in V$ such that, for every $f\in F$, we have $f(v)=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in K$.**

*(**Hint:** Use induction on dimension of $V$).*

*My attempt:*

Following the hint, we have that if $\dim V =1$ then there is $0\neq v\in V$ such that $V=\langle v\rangle$, in this case, $f(v)\in V=\langle v\rangle$ for every $f\in F$, then we have that for every $f\in F$, there is a $\lambda_f$ such that $f(v)=\lambda_f\cdot v$.

So, we have the first step done.

*Now, I'm having problem (dubs wit my attemp here) with the inductive step:*

Let's suppose of result true for $\dim V= n>1$ until $n-1$ and let's prove true that for $n$.

We have a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ for $V$, then $W=\langle v_1,...,v_{n-1}\rangle$ have dimension $n-1$ and we can find a $v\in W$ such that $f(v)=\lambda v$ for every $f\in F$. Now, $W\subset V$ then $v\in V$ having the property of $f(v)=\lambda v$ for every $f\in F$. Is it correct? (I'm not using that $F$ is a a familily of triangularizable commutative operators )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are the linear operators in your family operators on $W$? Because it can happen that $f(W)\not\subset W$.

Comment: Is $K$ algebraically closed ?

Comment: The word "commutative" in the title and question are not in the right place. Operators are not commutative, families of them can be.

Answer (score 1):

We need to reason a little more precisely.

The proof is in fact conveniently conducted by induction on the dimension of $V$. Here are the basic steps:

1. Choose an operator $f\in F$ such that $f\neq \alpha I$, where $I$ is an identical operator, $\alpha\in K$.
2. Let $\lambda\in K$ be the eigenvalue of $f$ (since $f$ is triangular, there is such an eigenvalue). Denote by $W=\{v\in V\mid f(v)=\lambda v\}$. By choice $f$ we have $W\neq V$.
3. Now prove that $g(W)\subset W$ for all $g\in F$. Here you will need the fact that the operators commutate.
4. By induction ($\dim W<\dim V$) in $W$ there exists a vector $w\in W$ ($w\neq0$) such that $g(w)=\lambda_gw$ for all $g\in F$.

Comment: Where do you use the fact that the operators are  triangularizable ?

Comment: @Lelouch I've only outlined the basic steps. Triangularity is used in the second step. And again in step 4.
Algebraic closure of the field is not needed in this problem.